# Make child fill 100% of parent with padding

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a child `div` using 100% (including padding) of the parents' width and height. Whatever I try it's not working. I tried to add `box-sizing = border-box` but that didn't change anything. I also tried to add the box-sizing to all elements using `*` but that didn't change anything either.
Here's my code:

```css
html {
  font-size: 16px;
}

.parent {
  font-size: 1rem;
  width: 10em;
  height: 10em;
  padding: 5em;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
}

.child {
  background-color: #ccc;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  
/* 
--= 100% should include padding =--
box-sizing: border-box; <-- this didn't change anything...
*/
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Seems like you are trying to do something that's not meant to work that way. Why don't you just take the child out of parent or remove the padding from the parent? If there are other elements that needs the padding then wrap them in an another element with the padding so whatever needs padding put it in the wrapper the ones does not need it, leave the wrapper off

Answer (score 5):

A child will be placed outside its parent's padding if it is positioned absolutely, relative to the parent.
Use [`position:absolute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Types_of_positioning) like so:

```
.parent {
  position: relative;
  padding: 2em;
}

.child {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

---

**Demonstration:**

```css
html {
  font-size: 12px;
}
body {
  margin: 1em;
}

.parent {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  width: 10em;
  padding: 2em;
  margin:1em 0 0;
  background-color: blue;
  border: 5px solid red;
}

.child {
  position: relative;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

.background {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
}
.red {
  color: red;
}
.blue {
  color: blue;
}
.green {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<p>Parent Border: <span class="red">Red</span></p>
<p>Parent Background: <span class="blue">Blue</span> (not visible)</p>
<p>Child Background: <span class="green">Green</span></p>

<div class="parent">
  <div class="child background"></div>
  <div class="child">This text to indicate parent's padding</div>
</div>
```

**Working Example with your code:**

```css
html {
  font-size: 16px;
}

.parent {
  position: relative; /* ADDED */
  font-size: 1rem;
  width: 10em;
  height: 10em;
  padding: 5em;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
}

.child {
  position: absolute; /* ADDED */
  left: 0; /* ADDED */
  top :0; /* ADDED */
  background-color: #ccc;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

---

**An Explanation:**

> In the *absolute positioning* model, a box is explicitly offset with respect to its **containing block**.

[Absolute positioning @ w3](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#absolute-positioning)

> If the position property is *static or relative*, the containing block is formed by the edge of the **content box** of the nearest ancestor element that is a block container...
>
> If the position property is *absolute*, the containing block is formed by the edge of the **padding box** of the nearest ancestor element that has a position value other than static (fixed, absolute, relative, or sticky).

[Identifying the containing block @ moz](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Containing_block#Identifying_the_containing_block)

*Emphasis and bold added by me.*

Further reference: [box model](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html)

Comment: I like this better because it doesn't create a mathematical dependency on the parent's style values.

Answer (score 3):

The only way to do this without changing the parent is by overriding the parent element's padding. To do this, you need to set the `width` and `height` to `calc(100% + 10em)`. You will also need to negate the left and top padding to position the element correctly. Set the child to have `position: relative` and set `left` and `top` to be `-5em`.

```css
html {
  font-size: 16px;
}

.parent {
  font-size: 1rem;
  width: 10em;
  height: 10em;
  padding: 5em;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
}

.child {
  background-color: #ccc;
  width: calc(100% + 10em);
  height: calc(100% + 10em);
  position: relative;
  left: -5em;
  top: -5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your child should set it's margin to the parent's padding amount multiplied by -1. This will move the component back to it's original position before padding was added to the parent. This can be applied to any and all directions.

Because of the added padding to the parent, the parent's size increased. In the horizontal direction this increase in size is the left-padding added to the right-padding. And vertically, the top-padding added to the bottom padding.

```css
html {
  font-size: 16px;
}

.parent {
  font-size: 1rem;
  width: 10em;
  height: 10em;
  padding: 5em;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
}

.child {
  background-color: #ccc;
  width: calc(100% + 5em + 5em); /* parent's width + left-padding + right-padding */
  height: calc(100% + 5em + 5em); /* parent's height + top-padding + bottom-padding */
  margin: calc(5em * -1); /* The negative of parent's padding */
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

In your case specifically, the following simplified child component will suffice:

```css
.child {
  background-color: #ccc;
  width: 200%;
  height: 200%;
  margin: -5em;
}
```